# cassandra nodetool listsnapshots failed with java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

Cassandra 4.0 is installed in Azure Kubernetes ubuntu 18.04.1 with 3 nodes and RF=3. Node repair is running by reaper 3.0.0.  At the same time, run "nodetool listsnapshots" failed with the exceptions. What could be the reason?

$ nodetool listsnapshots
Snapshot Details:
error: org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogFile
-- StackTrace --

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogFile
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```